# Two switching wall warts for a regulated bipolar supply?

Tags: power-supply

Can I connect in series two identical switching wall wart supplies (12 V each) that have no measurable resistance between either DC output pin and either ac pin (measure open and have no ground plug) to make a regulated power supply (±9 V) like this? If so, any hints on how to improve the circuit? I want to power a headphone amp with 300 mA and need a quiet supply.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. No problems at all. In order to use them for low noise schematics, provide good filtering of the linear regulators. Use low inductance ceramics capacitors in parallel with the electrolytic capacitors in the input and output filters. Keep the linear and switching regulators on some distance.

Comment: It may also be advisable to add a series inductor and a second set of filter caps down wind from the inductor. I would place these between the switch mode units and the linear regulators to help remove switch noise on the +12 and -12V.

Comment: @MichaelKaras - yes, I though about it as well. But IMHO, it will be a little bit over-engineered this way. At least without first trying with simple filters. That is why I didn't wrote it in the answer. :)

Comment: A good answer dude. You're getting the idea +1 (just as I did a few months ago)

Comment: What do you mean by "Keep the linear and switching regulators on some distance"?

Comment: @Rubistro - well, the same distance measured in meters. I mean in order to avoid EMI by capacitive or inductive link. How big the distance should be depends on the whole design.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was planning to make a switching "brick" with both switching supplies in it and keep it on the floor near the AC outlet. Then wire the switched DC from the "brick" to the amp where filtration and regulation would take place. The whole point is why waste all those switchers that are being thrown away? Free parts that do the job are one heck of a good deal.